# php join query - array results

Tags: php, mysql

Here are my tables:

```
units_main:
FACID----sub_key-----ASGMT_Name
AR01____1000_______LEGAL COMMAND
AR01____1001_______OPPS 67
AR02____1002_______REG D


units_sub:
FACID-----sub_key-----Long_Name
AR01_____1000_______cmd a, b and sometimes c
AR01_____1000_______secondary cmd structrue
AR01_____1001_______opps seg 798 b
AR02_____1002_______s cmd structure cc8
```

I'm passing a FACID to the query via $_GET variable in URL to login page, then the $_GET gets set to a $_SESSION variable. Based on this FACID, i'd like to query units_main, then join records from units_sub via sub_key.

```
Here's my query:

$real_facid = $_SESSION['facid'];
$query = "SELECT m.FACID
 , m.sub_key
 , m.ASGMT_Name
 , s.Long_Name
FROM units_main AS m
LEFT OUTER
JOIN units_sub AS s
ON s.FACID = m.FACID
AND s.sub_key = m.sub_key
WHERE m.FACID = '$real_facid'
ORDER
BY m.FACID
, m.sub_key
, s.Long_Name";
```

Here I run the query and grab the array:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $rows['ASGMT_Name'];
echo $rows['Long_Name'];}
```

The query works, but for FACID=AR01, I get the following results:

```
LEGAL COMMAND
cmd a, b and sometimes c
LEGAL COMMAND
secondary cmd structrue
OPPS 67
opps seg 798 b
```

I want the returned results to look like this (notice the 2nd "LEGAL COMMAND" removed):

```
LEGAL COMMAND
----cmd a, b and sometimes c
----secondary cmd structrue
OPPS 67
----opps seg 798 b
```

I know i'd have to loop over the array, but I'm really struggling with it...any kinda help would be appreciated!

Thanks for the help!

**Edit (Dec 6th)**
Here was the Final, working script:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $res = array();
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        { 
            //echo $rows['ASGMT_Name'];
            if (!array_key_exists($rows['ASGMT_Name'], $res))
            {
                $res[$rows['ASGMT_Name']] = array();
            }

            //for some reason this didn't work?
            //$values = $res[$rows['ASGMT_Name']];

            $var = $rows['Long_Name'];
            array_push($res[$rows['ASGMT_Name']],$var);

        }
                    print_r($res);
```

I want to add 2 more levels to the beginning of the $res array, i.e.:

name -> branch -> ASGMT_Name -> Long_Name

I tried this, but it's not working, the 'LEGAL COMMAND' needs to be the index of the array just before it....:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $res = array();
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))

        {   //print_r($rows);
            //echo $rows['ASGMT_Name'];

            $res[$rows['name']] = array($rows['branch'] => array());
                //$var = $rows['branch'];
                //array_push($res[$rows['name']],$var);

            if (!array_key_exists($rows['ASGMT_Name'], $res))
            {
                $res[$rows['ASGMT_Name']] = array();
            }

            $var = $rows['Long_Name'];
            array_push($res[$rows['ASGMT_Name']],$var);

        }
        print_r($res);
```

Here's the output from the above:

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [branch] => Array ( ) )[LEGAL COMMAND] => 
Array ( [0] => cmd a, b and sometimes c [1] => cmd a, b and sometimes c)
```

any help?

thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
$res = array();
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  if (!array_key_exists($res, $rows['ASGMT_Name']))
  {
      $res[$rows['ASGMT_Name']] = array();
  }
  $values = $res[$rows['ASGMT_Name']];
  array_push($values,$rows['Long_Name'];)     
}
```

Now you have hierarchical data in `$res`.

Comment: should it be array_push($res, $values, $rows['Long_Name']); ?

Comment: Nope, if I understood you well. It should be as it is in the answer. Again, unless I misunderstood the question...

Comment: hum, no matter what I do, I'm able to access the key in $res, but the value is another array. foreach($res as $mname => $name)
{echo $mname; if(is_array($name) { foreach($name as $ikey => $ivalue) { echo $ikey; echo $ivalue;}}}       $mname prints great, but I can't get anything to print for the $name array?

Comment: for some reason, the array() stored in the 'value' of $res[key] wasn't being populated. I changed to...

Comment: $var = $rows['Long_Name'];    array_push($res[$rows['ASGMT_Name']],$var);